# Calculate probability for two discrete variables in R

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

So, I have something like:

```
V1 V2
X  B
Y  A
X  A
Y  B
X  B
X  B
```

And I need:

```
    A     B
X  0.17  0.5
Y  0.17  0.17
```

*Note: They do not sum up to 1 because I round `1.666` to `1.7.*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`table` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/table.html) to create tables of counts:

```
> table(df)
   V2
V1  A B
  X 1 3
  Y 1 1
```

The table of probabilities is derived from this in a straightforward way:

```
> table(df) / nrow(df)
   V2
V1          A         B
  X 0.1666667 0.5000000
  Y 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Or, alternatively, using [`prop.table`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/prop.table.html):

```
> prop.table(table(df))
   V2
V1          A         B
  X 0.1666667 0.5000000
  Y 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
table(df)/nrow(df)
#    V2
# V1          A         B
#   X 0.1666667 0.5000000
#   Y 0.1666667 0.1666667
```